# How to plot annotations on every axes of lmplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm now practicing machine-learning and I would like to add annotations on clustering plots.

Here I'm using soil samples data, and trying to divide them into several groups. When I focus on a specific element I would like to see the correlations of other elements or find out the sample IDs and look them on a map. I'm now trying to put ID on the plots but I'm not sure how to do it with lmplots.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

data=pd.read_csv("E:\Programming\Python\Matplotlib\Geochemi_test3.csv", index_col=0) #reading my dataset

data_x = data.drop(labels=["E","N","B_ppm","Geology","Height"], axis=1)
data_y=data["Geology"]


from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

model = PCA(n_components=2)
model.fit(data_x)
X_2D = model.transform(data_x)
data['PCA1'] = X_2D[:, 0]
data['PCA2'] = X_2D[:, 1]
#sns.lmplot("PCA1", "PCA2", data=data, hue="Geology", fit_reg=False)


from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture as GMM
model = GMM(n_components=4,covariance_type='full')
model.fit(data_x)
y_gmm = model.predict(data_x)


data['cluster'] = y_gmm

fgrid = sns.lmplot("PCA1", "PCA2", data=data, hue="Se_ppm", col="cluster",fit_reg=False)
ax = fgrid.axes[0,0]
p1=sns.regplot(data=data, x="PCA1", y="PCA2", fit_reg=False, marker="o", scatter_kws={'s':10})

for line in range(0,data.shape[0]):
     p1.text(data.PCA1[line]+0.2, data.PCA2[line], data.index[line], horizontalalignment='left', size='medium', color='black', weight='semibold')
```

The result of this code I get this plot.
[image]
Is it possible to add annotations on each axes? Here annotations are only shown on the right axes.
As I searched about annotations I only could find plotting on regplot. Can I annotate on lmplot as well which is divided by columns?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why the annotations are not lining up, and Facet Grids have never been my forte, however you may also want to look into this module adjust_text, it will make the annotations much easier to read as well. https://github.com/Phlya/adjustText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return of `lmplot` is a `FacetGrid`. You need to specify each Axes object within the FacetGrid to annotate each one. Something like this:

```
for ax in fgrid.axes:
    for line in range(0,data.shape[0]): 
        ax.text(...)
```

However, you seem to have overwritten the last Axes object with your `regplot` call. I'm not sure if that's intentional.

Comment: It isn't intentional. I made a mistake around that part. I am now trying to sort out the axes.

Comment: From the name FacetGrid, I tried to find out how to plot text in each axes but I couldn't find a way to do so. However, sorry for my late reply. I might need to close this, and try doing this with a different approach.

Comment: You can definitely add text to each axes in a FacetGrid. You need to get the axes objects using `fgrid.axes`. This will be an array of the axes in the FacetGrid in the same layout as the actual figure. So to add text to the first axes for instance, you would do something like `fgrid.axes[0,0].text(x, y, 'text')`

Comment: Thank you for the additional info. However, I get `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>` when I try to select the axes with `fgrid.axes[0,0]`. Is there anyway to avoid this?

Comment: That seems like an odd error to get when you run `fgrid.axes[0,0]`. Are you sure that's where the error is occurring? Is there anything else that you are trying to execute on the same line?

Comment: No, even writing `fgrid.axes[0,0]` soon after `fgrid = sns.lmplot(...)`will cause this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `fgrid.axes[0,0].text(x, y, 'text')` soon after the lmplot. Without this it works fine with no label. However, I am using Python 3.6.6 and Seaborn 0.9.0.

Comment: I found that there was a problem in x and y data, and could solve the problem. Now I need to pickup the labels just I need. However, your answer solved the question of lmplot axes grid, so I will vote up. Thank you very much for helping.